# Use onfocus event in Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, plugin-contact-form-7

I would like to use the onfocus event on my contact form.
The onfocus event essentially is used to make an API call using java-script.

So far, I've tried focus(), but this applies to every input tag, and I cannot get it to stick to the input field ID(Yes, its unique) and onclick, but this is a bit more cumbersome.

This is the field where I would want to call my API

Email Address[email* your-email id:focuseventfire class:txt class:form-control placeholder "EMAIL"]

I would like some guidance or documentation on how to make this happen or even a possible solution or even an alternative to this.to this.